# MySQL: Order of columns changes after LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, key, schema

I want to join the two tables *information_schema.COLUMNS* and *information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE* by doing the following:

```
SELECT
    a.COLUMN_NAME AS name,
    c.COLUMN_TYPE,
    ...
    b.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA AS ref_db,
    b.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME AS ref_table,
    b.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME AS ref_col
FROM
    information_schema.COLUMNS AS a
LEFT JOIN
    information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS b
ON 
    a.TABLE_SCHEMA = b.TABLE_SCHEMA
AND
    a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME
AND
    a.COLUMN_NAME = b.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE
    a.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db'
AND
    a.TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
```

Unfortunately, MySQL changes the sequence of columns as they are set in the underlying *information_schema.COLUMNS* table and lists those columns on top, that actually have an index set in the *information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE* table.

The behavior, in which records that have matches in both tables are listed on top, seems to be the one to be expected. Nevertheless I'd like to keep the sequence of the base *COLUMNS* table.

Switching tables and using RIGHT JOIN instead didn't help.

Is there a way to ORDER BY original entry sequence?

---

#### Solved

Found a solution. Just edit the following:

```
ORDER BY
    a.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: You should delete your question.  If you want results from a query in a particular order, you need to use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I should not. Stackoverflow appreciates questions even when they are answered by the questioner himself (see guidelines). Had a long search for finding this solution using ORDINAL_POSITION. So maybe it helps someone. Thank you anyway